# can't get flask-moment to display dates in safari

Tags: python, flask, safari, momentjs

I'm trying to teach myself Flask, but I'm hitting the snag that I'm unable to display dates using flask-moment with Safari (13.0.2). They display fine in Chrome. A minimal app to demonstrate this behavior is below.

I'm not experienced enough with web dev to discern whether this is a bug in flask-moment, a bug in moment.js, a bug in jQuery, or just a misunderstanding that I could fix with some minor change somewhere. I've tried editing the markup that gets sent to the browser, but I've had no luck there. Specifically I changed the attribute "display: none" to "display: inline", but this resulted in non-formatted timestamps to be displayed rather than formatted dates (I guess that's better than nothing at all?).

On the other hand, a working minimal javascript example shows that it's not a moment.js / Safari issue per se, but I guess has something to do with the jQuery / bootstrap magic happening behind the scenes.

main.py:

```
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_moment import Moment
from flask import Flask, render_template
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
moment = Moment(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', current_time=datetime.utcnow())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

base.html:

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% block head %}
{{ super() }}
  {% block scripts %}
  {{ super() }}
  {{ moment.include_moment() }}
  {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  {% block page_content %}
  {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

index.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block page_content %}
Current time: {{ moment(current_time).format('LLL') }}.
{% endblock %}
```

Safari output:
[image]

Chrome output:
[image]

Edit: A helpful comment suggested I use the Safari dev tools to look into the issue. When I load the javascript console I see some errors pop up:

[image]

After some Googling I determined I needed to add a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, and updated my view function to:

```
from flask import make_response

...

@app.route("/")
def index():
    resp = make_response(render_template('index.html', current_time=datetime.utcnow()))
    resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    return resp
```

Unfortunately I get the exact same set of errors. I also tried the flask-cors library, which contains a `cross_origin` decorator that should presumably account for this issue, but the results are still the same.

Edit 2: I've "fixed" the issue. The `include_moment()` function contains an argument `sri` (for "subresource integrity") which, if true, checks whether the resource being fetched has been manipulated. If I set this to false the errors go away and the date displays fine. I would be curious if this can be fixed without disabling the check ...

Comment: Safari devtools console may indicate JS errors, which could help debug.

Comment: You should add it as a response so that it gets more visibility and you get credit for it. It definitely helped me out.